# r markdown prints integer instead of float

Tags: r, markdown

I have a small problem with R markdown.

When I want to print a number it works fine when I run "Run Current Chunk". 
However the "Knit HTML" unexpectedly prints an integer.

How can I print numbers as intended in R markdown?

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
print(20145.1234)
```
````

Result:

```
print(20145.1234)
## [1] 20145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an option for number of printed digits.

````
```{r}
options(digits = 9)
print(20145.1234)
```
````

or

````
```{r}
print(20145.1234, digits = 9)
```
````

which gives the following result

```
## [1] 20145.1234
```